# Как считать два целых числа и вывести наибольшее?

Tags: visual-c++

> Напишите программу, которая считывает два целых числа a и b и выводит наибольшее значение из них. Числа — целые от 1 до 1000.
>
> При решении задачи можно пользоваться только целочисленными арифметическими операциями +, -, *, //, %, =. Нельзя пользоваться нелинейными конструкциями: ветвлениями, циклами, функциями вычисления модуля, извлечения квадратного корня.

Comment: Учитесь давать вопросам толковые названия, пожалуйста.

Comment: я недавно на этом сайте и я особо не понял как задавать вопрос

Comment: Потратьте немного времени, осмотритесь, прочитайте справку ..

Comment: К сожалению, на этом сайте не делают задания за вас. Пробуйте сделать сами, а если не получится -- покажите свое решение, вам подскажут, в чем проблема.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/315412

Comment: @dIm0n А че прикольная задачка... Тока нагуглить легко...Слишком легко, даже подумать не успеваешь ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << (a*(a/b)+b*(b/a))/(b/a+a/b) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```